# Referencing data in Vue async function

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

In one of my components I use Axios to get responses from various api sources. It all works fine when I run serve but not when I build.

I believe it is because I'm not understanding how to properly do the async functions with Vue so that it complies with TypeScript type checking and tried various things but had no success so far.

**checkin.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "checkin",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      myCoordinates: {
        longitude: "",
        latitude: ""
      },
      myAddress: {
        city: "",
        country: "",
        country_code: "",
        county: "",
        neighbourhood: "",
        postcode: "",
        road: "",
        state: ""
      },
      addressName: "",
      timeZone: "",
      currentTime: "",
      temperature: "",
      description: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchDetails() {
      this.setAddress();
      this.setTimezone();
      this.setWeather();
    },
    addCheckin() {
      const checkInDetails = {
        long: this.myCoordinates.longitude,
        lat: this.myCoordinates.latitude,
        localDate: this.currentTime,
        timezone: this.timeZone,
        city: this.myAddress.city || "undefined",
        state: this.myAddress.state || "undefined",
        country: this.myAddress.country || "undefined",
        temperature: this.temperature,
        description: this.description || "undefined"
      };
      console.log(checkInDetails);
      this.$store.dispatch("addCheckIn", checkInDetails);
    },

    async setCoordinates() {
      const coordinates: any = await this.currentCoordinates();
      this.myCoordinates.latitude = coordinates.latitude;
      this.myCoordinates.longitude = coordinates.longitude;
      return coordinates;
    },
    async setAddress() {
      const address = await this.addressByCoordinates();
      return address;
    },
    async setTimezone() {
      const getTimezone = await this.timezoneByCordinates();
      return getTimezone;
    },
    async setWeather() {
      const weather = await this.weatherByCoordinates();
      return weather;
    },
    async currentCoordinates() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          ({ coords }) => resolve(coords),
          error => reject(error)
        );
      });
    },
    addressByCoordinates: async function() {
      await axios
        .get("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse",{
          params: {
            format: "jsonv2",
            lat: this.myCoordinates.latitude,
            lon: this.myCoordinates.longitude,
            "accept-language": "en",
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("response", response);
          this.addressName = response.data.display_name;
          this.myAddress = response.data.address;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("error ", error);
        });
    },
    timezoneByCordinates: async function() {

      await axios
        .get("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone", {
          params: {
            key: "KEY",
            format: "json",
            by: "position",
            lat: this.myCoordinates.latitude,
            lng: this.myCoordinates.longitude
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("response", response);
          this.timeZone = response.data.abbreviation;
          this.currentTime = response.data.formatted;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("error ", error);
        });
    },
    weatherByCoordinates: async function() {

      await axios
        .get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", {
          params: {
            lat: this.myCoordinates.latitude,
            lon: this.myCoordinates.longitude,
            appid: "APPID",
            units: "metric"
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("response", response);
          this.temperature = response.data.main.temp;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("error ", error);
        });
    }
  }, // end of methods
  mounted() {
    this.setCoordinates();
  },
};
</script>
```

When I try and do npm run build I get error messages such as this:

```
175:23 Property 'myCoordinates' does not exist on type '{ fetchDetails(): void; addCheckin(): void; setCoordinates(): Promise<any>; setAddress(): Promise<void>; setTimezone(): Promise<void>; setWeather(): Promise<...>; currentCoordinates(): Promise<...>; addressByCoordinates: () => Promise<...>; timezoneByCordinates: () => Promise<...>; weatherByCoordinates: () => Promis...'. Did you mean 'setCoordinates'?
    173 |           params: {
    174 |             format: "jsonv2",
  > 175 |             lat: this.myCoordinates.latitude,
        |                       ^
    176 |             lon: this.myCoordinates.longitude,
    177 |             "accept-language": "en"
    178 |           }

283:10 Property 'setCoordinates' does not exist on type '{ name: string; components: {}; data(): { myCoordinates: { longitude: string; latitude: string; }; myAddress: { city: string; country: string; country_code: string; county: string; neighbourhood: string; postcode: string; road: string; state: string; }; ... 4 more ...; description: string; }; methods: { ...; }; moun...'.
    281 |   }, // end of methods
    282 |   mounted() {
  > 283 |     this.setCoordinates();
        |          ^
    284 |   },
    285 |   computed: {}
    286 | };
```

I've also tried doing the functions as follows but it's the same problem

```
    async addressByCoordinates() {
      ...
    },
```

The debug log states the following:

```
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ashle_000\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error travelling@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the travelling@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've looked into ELIFECYCLE and tried a few of the suggestions (clean cache, delete node_modules, install again etc) but no joy.

The data itself is fine, it just won't let me run npm run build and I can't figure out what I need to do in order to get it to work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Firt, you need to use the Vue.extend method in order to [allow Typescript to infer types](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage)

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    name: "checkin",
    components: {},
    methods: {
        // ...
    },
});
</script>
```

You also need to set the data types of the data object. Add type annotation for the returned object for the data function.

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({    
    data(): {
        myCoordinates: {
            longitude: string,
            latitude: string,
        },
        // add the rest of data types
        // ....
    } {
      return {
        myCoordinates: {
          longitude: "",
          latitude: ""
        },
        myAddress: {
          city: "",
          country: "",
          country_code: "",
          county: "",
          neighbourhood: "",
          postcode: "",
          road: "",
          state: ""
        },
        addressName: "",
        timeZone: "",
        currentTime: "",
        temperature: "",
        description: ""
      };
    },
});
</script>
```